# Remove comments from css file

Tags: php, regex

I have to read a css file and remove its commentaries, so i've decided to use the `preg_replace` function from php:

```
$original = '
/*
foo
*/
.test, input[type="text"]{ color: blue; }

/* bar */
a:hover{
text-decoration: underline;
color: red;
background: #FFF;
}';

echo preg_replace('/\/\*.*\*\//s', '', $original);
```

the problem is that its losing the line  `.test, input[type="text"]{ color: blue; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `.*` to `.*?`.

```
echo preg_replace('#/\*.*?\*/#s', '', $original);
```

This will only remove `/*` up to the closest `*/` rather than the furthest.

Comment: Like a charm. Thanks for the fast and precise answer. May i ask, why the interrogation is matching the closest? I mean, its a '0 or 1 ocurrences' match isn't it?

Comment: @Carlos not in this case.  See http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.repetition.php

Answer (score 0):

I would approach it as follows:

```
\/\*((?!\*\/).*?)\*\/


\/\*            # Start-of-comment
((?!\*\/).*?)   # Any character 0 or more times, lazy,
                #   without matching an end-of-comment
\*\/            # End-of-comment
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yexONT/2)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$buffer = preg_replace('/\*[^*]*\*+([^/][^*]*\*+)*/', '', $buffer);
```

It doesn't work for `//Comments here`, but it works for the rest of `/* Comment here */`, even for multiple lines.

for `//Comments here`, use this one:

```
$buffer = preg_replace('/\/\*.*?\*\//s', '', $buffer);
```